# Joomla 2.5 module permissions

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I simply want to make a module visible dependent on whether a user belongs to a custom set of groups - including NOT visible if (s)he belongs to a particular group(s). For example, adverts show for public and registered but not a custom "premium" group. A shoutbox should appear for registered and premium but not "not logged in". Thus, the "guest" and "special" groups are pretty useless as far as I can tell. Am I missing something really simple?

If I *have* to use a 3rd party component/module to achieve this then a free or cheap one would be most beneficial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to edit and create new access levels. To cover up the examples you gave in the question, the following could work:

You need to get the guests out of the root parent group called *Public*. You can do this by the following three steps:

1. Using the *User Manager*, create a new group called *"Guest"* with *Public* as parent.
2. Open up the *User Manager Options*.
3. Change *Guest User Group* to your new group *Guest*.

The guests on your site will from now on be put into the *Guest* group. Now you could create a access level for the advert. So create a new access level, name it something like *"Non premium users"* and add *Guest* and *Registered*. Now apply this access level to the module and it should work. Note that the premium group cannot have *Registered* as a parent.

Next is the access level for the shoutbox. I see two options for this access level. One of them is to create a new access level and add *Registered* and *Premium* to it. A simpler approach though is to add the *Premium* group to the already existing access level called *Registered*.

Helpful ACL Links:

- [Allowing Guest-Only Access to Menu Items and Modules](http://docs.joomla.org/Access_Control_List/1.6-2.5/Tutorial#Allowing_Guest-Only_Access_to_Menu_Items_and_Modules)
- [Joomla ACL: Access Levels](http://magazine.joomla.org/issues/issue-feb-2012/item/639-Joomla-ACL-Access-Levels)

Answer (score 0):

None of the ACL levels work 100% of the time for me, I had to hack the template I was using and add in some code...

```
<?php  

// make sure user is an accepted user group 
jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
$userId = $user->get( 'id' );
$groups = JUserHelper::getUserGroups($userId);

// print_r($groups); 
/* 
3 Author
4 Editor
5 Publisher
6 Manager
7 Administrator
8 Super Users
*/ 

$menu = '' ;
if (in_array("3", $groups)) {
       // echo "<!-- Author Group Found! -->";
        // echo '<!-- USER ID: ' . $userId . ' -->';
        $menu .= "
        <a href='http://yourdomain.com/authors-area'>Authors Area</a> 
        " ;
} elseif(in_array("4", $groups)) { 
$menu .= "
        <a href='http://yourdomain.com/editors-area'>Editors Area</a> 
        " ;
} elseif(in_array("5", $groups)) { 
$menu .= "
        <a href='http://yourdomain.com/publishers-area'>Publishers Area</a> 
        " ;
} elseif(in_array("6", $groups)) { 
$menu .= "
        <a href='http://yourdomain.com/managers-area'>Managers Area</a> 
        " ;
} elseif(in_array("7", $groups)) { 
$menu .= "
        <a href='http://yourdomain.com/administrators-area'>Administrators Area</a> 
        " ;
} elseif(in_array("8", $groups)) { 
$menu .= "
        <a href='http://yourdomain.com/superusers-area'>Super Users Area</a> 
        " ;
} else {
    $null = '' ; ;
    }
?>
```